# LINQ query skips debug and does not execute next line

Tags: c#, .net, linq, debugging

I have searched already for answers for this with no luck.

I have a simple LINQ query that when I step over in DEBUG (VS2010), I get no error/exception but the next line of code is never reached.

Here is my code:

```
var model = actionLogRepository.Query()
                .Take(30)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDateTime)
                .ToList();

return PartialView(model);
```

DEBUG hits the 'var model' line of code and F10 steps over but the 'return' line is not reached.

Can anyone tell me what is happening here?

Comment: how many lines have you in actionLogRepository table and does LogDateTime have an indexer ?

Comment: you could assign "model" without "ToList()" and then have a look in Watchlist, what your query looks like and execute it in your dbms

Comment: As @Ksv3n implies that query might take awhile to complete,  how long have you waited?  Did you ever get an error, or did you stop the debugger manually?

Comment: My guess is that an error occurs within the .Query method which will get caught by MVC but remain unhandled somehow

Comment: Call ToList() after the Take(30) and then Sort.

Comment: check if Compiler Optimizations are on from your project settings

Answer (score 0):

Since your LINQ gets data from a database, I would check first how long it takes to get data from database. It might be that Debugger waits till data comes back from a database, and your database is running slow.

You can get your SQL that is generated by EF from

```
var query = ((ObjectQuery)model).ToTraceString();
```

Or set up your Context to output queries

```
using (var context = new YourDatabaseEntities())
{
    context.Database.Log = x => Debug.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad. This is useful to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Fixed but still not sure why. My actionLogRepository.Query() method returns a IEnumerable object. For some reason this just didn't do anything. I removed my repository call with the following and all now works.

```
        var model = db.ActionLogs
                        .Take(30)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.LogDateTime)
                        .ToList();
```

model is now just returning a generic List of ActionLog. I guess if I changed my Query method to return a generic List it would also work.

UPDATE 2:

Having now changed my Query methood to return a DbSet instead of IEnumerable with type ActionLog, my original code now works.

```
    public DbSet<ActionLog> Query()
```

Thank you all for your speedy responses.

Comment: Thanks Guys for giving me some guidance so quickly.

Comment: Are you sure it returns an IEnumerable? It should be an IQueryable. Also, this is expected behaviour. You will not see anything in the debugger right after the Query without enumerating it first.

Comment: I have updated my Query method to return a DbSet of type ActionLog and this works perfectly now. My model is now returning a List of type ActionLog because of the .ToList() which is fine for the PartialView that consumes it.